# E/SQLiteLog: (1) table keyTable has no column named number

Tags: java, android, database

I keep getting this error:

> "table keyTable has no column named number"

Still pretty new to Android, so no clue why this happens, can anyone spot the error?

This is my Database class:

```
public class KeyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String database_name = "KeyDatabase.db";
    private static final int database_version = 1;

KeyDatabase (Context context){
    super(context,database_name,null,database_version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + KeyTableClass.table_name
            + "(" + KeyTableClass.id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KeyTableClass.number + " TEXT, "
            + KeyTableClass.key + " TEXT);");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KeyTableClass.table_name);
    onCreate(db);
}

public long InsertKey (String number, String key){
    ContentValues valuesToInsert = new ContentValues();

    valuesToInsert.put(KeyTableClass.number, number);
    valuesToInsert.put(KeyTableClass.key, key);

    SQLiteDatabase sd = getWritableDatabase();

    long result = sd.insert(KeyTableClass.table_name, KeyTableClass.number, valuesToInsert);

    return result;
}
```

This is my class for my table:

```
public class KeyTableClass {
//The name of the table
public static final String table_name = "keyTable";

//The columns of the table
public static String id = "id";
public static String number = "number";
public static String key = "key";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've edited the DB `onCreate` but didn't let it re-run?
Try uninstalling/install the App, Or update `database_version` to =2.

Answer (score 1):

You don't fit the [requirements for the insertion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) :

```
public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

> Added in API level 1 Convenience method for inserting a row into the
>   database.
>
> Parameters table  the table to insert the row into
>   nullColumnHack    optional; may be null. SQL doesn't allow inserting a
>   completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your
>   provided values is empty, no column names are known and an empty row
>   can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter
>   provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL
>   into in the case where your values is empty. values   this map contains
>   the initial column values for the row. The keys should be the column
>   names and the values the column values Returns the row ID of the newly
>   inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

Could you try to do :

`sb.insert(table_name, null, valuesToInsert);`

Comment: Made the change so now I have this line:

long result = sd.insert(KeyTableClass.table_name, null, valuesToInsert);

I still seem to get the error, I might have misunderstood what you said.